# laravel eloquent error in saving password

Tags: authentication, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to learn how to use Laravel and until now I haven't had any problem.
Then I tried to implements an example of Authentication.

1) I created a migration file where i set the User table (password is set to 60, the token is set to 100 following the instructions on laravel site)

2) I used a seeder to generate fake users:

```
$faker = Faker::create();

        foreach(range(1, 10) as $index)
        {
            User::create([
                'firstname' => $faker->firstName(),
                'lastname'  => $faker->lastName(),
                'email'     => $faker->email(),
                'password'  => Hash::make('password'),
                'telephone' => $faker->phoneNumber(),
                'admin'     => rand(0,1)
            ]);
        }
```

The table in the database is perfectly seeded without problem.

3) I created a controller UserController with the following function

public function postCreate() {
    $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), User::$rules);

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::to('users/newaccount')->with('message','error')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
}

unset($data['password_confirmation']);
$data['password'] = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
User::create($data);

return Redirect::to('users/signin')->with('message','thanks');
```

}

4) I created a form for register the user

```
{{ Form::open(array('route'=>array('users.createaccount'), 'method' => 'post')) }}
        .....
            {{ Form::label('password') }}
            {{ Form::password('password') }}
        ....
        {{ Form::submit('Create new account') }}
        {{ Form::close() }}
```

Problem is when i check on the DB table the user is register and saved, and all the fields are filled except for the password (and the token that remains null)..

But if i do a dd($data) before calling User::create($data) this is what i can see:

```
array(6) { ["_token"]=> string(40) "5bSkWYHLfeBh8E2agiB15J2cQSzs6orI7m5ruFhx" ["firstname"]=> string(4) "mark" ["lastname"]=> string(4) "mark" ["email"]=> string(13) "mark@mark.com" ["password"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$J3eM3nBZ0l8eNa1BxpoDc.BzeQUKzTc7dwwbu7g7GdQLj4gJgjWxe" ["telephone"]=> string(8) "12345678" }
```

Anyone can tell me why only the password and the token fields are not saved with the Eloquent method in the database, while they are saved using the seeder?

thk

Comment: Is `password` present in the `$fillable` array?

Comment: uuuuuu..... yep, that's right... it was that,... do i also have to set the token inside the fillable array?... (how do i vote the answer?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All fields you want to pass to `create` need to be defined inside the `$fillable` array. Also `password`

```
protected $fillable = array('firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'telephone', 'admin');
                                                                  ^^
```

`_token` definitely doesn't need to be in there. It's just a token Laravel adds for [CSRF protection](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#protecting-routes)